# Does Chromecast or Amazon Fire TV Stick work with a computer monitor?

Tags: display, hdmi, chromecast

I'm interested in knowing whether these media streaming sticks work with regular PC monitors (with HDMI ports), and not just HDTV. I couldn't find it in the product descriptions on their websites. Has anyone tested it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All it cares about is the receiving side can accept HDMI, be it a TV, monitor, or anything else. If it can display HDMI it will work.

The only issue you may run in to is if the monitor does not have any speakers you won't have a way to play the audio unless the monitor has some kind of audio out port.

Comment: The monitors in question all have built-in speakers. Thanks!

Comment: Just adding to the above answer so that anyone with just a monitor without speakers could be benefitted . Incase the monitor lacks speakers. you can easily connect the Fire Stick to bluetooth headphones or bluetooth speakers...

Comment: There are two newer answers that contradict this one. Maybe they are wrong; or maybe your answer had been fine but then some non-compliant hardware came up; or maybe this statement is just too confident: "If it can display HDMI it will work". Your answer, being the accepted one from a high-reputation user, may encourage someone to reckless shopping. I'm asking you to either back your statement up with something, or to explicitly acknowledge there may be exceptions. Frankly I can't imagine you could prove all hardware combinations work, so easing up on the statement seems the right thing to do.

Comment: There could also be a difference between Chromecast and Fire Stick, which could explain the differing experiences.

Answer (score 2):

The Fire Stick will not work on computer monitors or HDMI recorders. That's because the Fire Stick is looking for handshaking signals consistent with an HD television (e.g. HDCP copy protection). You can get around this by feeding the Fire Stick into an HDMI Splitter, and having a compliant TV receiver on one output, and your non-compliant monitor or recorder on the other output.

Comment: This contradicts information in the accepted answer- can you back his up?

Comment: I have test this out.. It works perfectly fine with monitors .. I have tried couple of monitors .HP 25 xi , Samsung and a Dell ...

Comment: This answer and the comments are not mutually exclusive.  The tested monitors could be capable of handshaking.

Comment: This is a complete lie. I use 2 fire sticks with 2 computer monitors just fine. I use a bluetooth speaker to get sound.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent over an hour today on the phone with Amazon tech support and with Samsung. I have a Samsung monitor and can get video, but no audio despite every possible reconfiguration of sound options, restarts, etc. The monitor works fine with cable TV. I came to the conclusion that it requires a real TV, as suggested above, but refuted below. May send the stick back to Amazon.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer and post the exact model of this Samsung monitor of yours?